# Accessing array object value in typescript model

Tags: angular, typescript

I am newbie to typescript and angular 2. I am finding it hard to access an array object value from a http response. Below is the code.

Below is the rdcModel defition

```
class RdcModel {
    constructor(
        public rdcList: Array<RdcList>
    ) { }
}
class RdcList {
    constructor(
        public rdcNumber: number,
        public rdcName: string,
    ) {}
}
export { RdcModel, RdcList };
```

using the below Api service to retrive the data and returning the rdcModel.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { RdcModel } from './model/rdc.model';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient) {}
    getRdc$(): Observable<RdcModel[]> {
        return this.http
          .get('https://web.server.com/RDCUI/rs/rdc')
          .catch(this._handleError);
      }
      private _handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse | any) {
        const errorMsg = err.message || 'Error: Unable to complete request.';
        return Observable.throw(errorMsg);
      }
}
```

Below is the response that I get when I call the api.

```
{
   "rdcList":[
      {
         "rdcNumber":8756,
         "rdcName":"DALLAS"
      },
      {
         "rdcNumber":4251,
         "rdcName":"TOPEKA"
      }
   ]
}
```

In the component, I am trying to access the rdclist[1]

```
rdcModel: RdcModel[] = [];
  this.dcSub = this.api
      .getRdc$().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.rdcModel = res;
        console.log(this.rdcModel[0]);
      },
      err => {console.error(err); }
      );
```

It gives me undefined when I try to acess [0]. How should I access the values of each RDC and store it an array? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't you console.log `this.rdcModel.rdcList[0]` ?

Comment: It gives me an error "property rdcList does not exists on 'RdcModel[]' "

Comment: Remove the array from the type and it should be ok. Your API is returning `RdcModel`, not `RdcModel[]`

Comment: It gives me an error "property rdcList does not exists on 'RdcModel[]' " when I do webpack build. But in console, It is printing proper value. Should I ignore the error ?
ERROR in src/app/header/header.component.ts(27,35): error TS2339: Property 'rdcList' does not exist on type 'RdcModel[]'.
src/app/header/header.component.ts(28,45): error TS2339: Property 'rdcList' does not exist on type 'RdcModel[]'.
src/app/header/header.component.ts(29,37): error TS2339: Property 'rdcList' does not exist on type 'RdcModel[]'.

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if you face any issues

Comment: @Axnyff and Prithivi. Both of your suggestions works and I am able to access the values. My only concern is compilation is giving me an error "error TS2339: Property 'rdcList' does not exist on type 'RdcModel[]'. should I ignore that error ? Thanks for your help

Comment: @Axnyff and Prithivi. Thank you for your help. Removing array type from rdcModel fixed the error message as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the below code. I am not sure whether your response is array of objects or not. if it's array of objects just iterate the rdcModel and put console to check

```
rdcModel: any;
  this.dcSub = this.api
      .getRdc$().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.rdcModel = res;
        console.log(this.rdcModel.rdcList[0]);
      },
      err => {console.error(err); }
      );
```

Comment: Thanks you. It works. One more change I had to do was to remove the type rdcModel[] to rdcModel as @axnyff suggested. You guys saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have created a model of how your data will look like..
**My Model is called ModelClass**

```
export interface ModelClass{
name: string;
age: number;
}
```

**Then create your array with the object type of ModelClass**

```
student: ModelClass[] = [];
```

**And how to get value in that array--> Assume this code is in for loop or forEach loop... or whatever looping style u r comfortable**

```
student[i].name;
student[i].age;
```

**i ---> is index of the loop... Try convert this in ur HTTP code..**